# FormGroup submit returning null Angular6

Tags: angular, angular6

On submit my formgroup only log null to the console.
Following is the html setup of my code. 
I have reduced it to one input to make the example easier.
I have followed the reactive-forms guide on angular, and I cant find anything I missed.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 offset-md-4">
        <h3>Fyll inn</h3>
        <form [formGroup]="addCarForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
          <label>
            Skiltnummer
            <input FormControlName="LicensePlate" class="form-control" />
          </label>
          <br />
          <button type="submit">Lagre</button>
          <button type="reset" (click)="revert()">Reset</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Following is my FormGroup stored in add-car.component.ts

```
export class AddCarComponent implements OnInit {
  addCarForm = new FormGroup({
    LicensePlate: new FormControl()
  });
```

Necessary imports is added to add-car.component.ts

```
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
```

In the app.module.ts I have imported ReactiveFormsModule

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

And added it to imports on the @NgModule under imports.

Comment: please share code of `onSubmit`

Comment: onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.addCarForm.value);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`formControlName` should be camel case

`<input formControlName="LicensePlate" class="form-control" />`